# I'm encountering a 404 issue while using Next.js Parallel Routes

Tags: next.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUvrp.png)

Is there something wrong with this folder structure? I cannot access the URL http://localhost:3000/lists/item. Can a folder containing Parallel Routes not create subpaths?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1xS7.png)

"Slots are not route segments and do not affect the URL structure. The file path /@team/members would be accessible at /members."

The Next.js Docs state that it is possible to access in this manner.